# Crash on NSManagedObjectContext Save Crashlytics

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, crashlytics, ios14

Application Get Crash while trying save or update record in coredata

**NSInvalidArgumentException - -[NSConcreteHashTable values]: unrecognized selector sent to instance**

Crash Details

```
    Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x9e48 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x178d8 objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x17e82c +[NSObject(NSObject) _copyDescription]
3  CoreFoundation                 0x1ff60 ___forwarding___
4  CoreFoundation                 0x88330 _CF_forwarding_prep_0
5  CoreData                       0x323ec -[NSSQLSavePlan _recordToManyChangesForObject:inRow:usingTimestamp:inserted:]
6  CoreData                       0x40a3c -[NSSQLSavePlan _createRowsForSave]
7  CoreData                       0xe87ac -[NSSQLSavePlan prepareRows]
8  CoreData                       0x1b2e0 -[NSSQLSaveChangesRequestContext executePrologue]
9  CoreData                       0x1b00c -[NSSQLCore dispatchRequest:withRetries:]
10 CoreData                       0x26500 -[NSSQLCore executeRequest:withContext:error:]
11 CoreData                       0x199078 __65-[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:]_block_invoke.551
12 CoreData                       0x61608 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator _routeHeavyweightBlock:]
13 CoreData                       0x25644 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:]
14 CoreData                       0x8d15c -[NSManagedObjectContext save:]
15                   0x2d30c DataController.updateRecord(_:object:) + 193 (DataController.swift:193)
16                   0x2e6ec DataController.removeAllLocalUrl() + 322 (DataController.swift:322)
17                   0x7f5a0 specialized closure #1 in AppDelegate.getUserInfoCallBack(_:email:completion:) + 643 (AppDelegate.swift:643)
18                   0x8d2a0 partial apply for closure #1 in AppDelegate.getUserInfoCallBack(_:email:completion:) (<compiler-generated>)
19                   0x8b9c8 partial apply for closure #1 in RestApiManager.makeHTTPPostRequest(_:jsonBody:onCompletion:) (<compiler-generated>)
20                   0x82350 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed @Sendable (@guaranteed Data?, @guaranteed NSURLResponse?, @guaranteed Error?) -> () (<compiler-generated>)
21 CFNetwork                      0x208d4 CFURLRequestSetMainDocumentURL
22 CFNetwork                      0x30958 _CFNetworkErrorCopyLocalizedDescriptionWithHostname
23 libdispatch.dylib              0x24b4 _dispatch_call_block_and_release
24 libdispatch.dylib              0x3fdc _dispatch_client_callout
25 libdispatch.dylib              0xb694 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain
26 libdispatch.dylib              0xc214 _dispatch_lane_invoke
27 libdispatch.dylib              0x16e10 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread
28 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xdf8 _pthread_wqthread
29 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xb98 start_wqthread

com.apple.main-thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x4aa8 mach_msg2_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x16fc4 mach_msg2_internal + 80
2  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x17204 mach_msg_overwrite + 388
3  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x4fec mach_msg + 24
4  CoreFoundation                 0x7aad4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160
5  CoreFoundation                 0x7bd18 __CFRunLoopRun + 1232
6  CoreFoundation                 0x80ec0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612
7  GraphicsServices               0x1368 GSEventRunModal + 164
8  UIKitCore                      0x3a186c -[UIApplication _run] + 888
9  UIKitCore                      0x3a14d0 UIApplicationMain + 340
10                   0x14100 main + 47 (AppDelegate.swift:47)
11 ???                            0x1c9312960 (Missing)
```

Code

```
 if object.localUrl != nil {
        record.setValue(object.localUrl, forKey: "localUrl")
    }else{
        record.setValue("", forKey: "localUrl")
    }
    
    if object.transcribe != nil {
        record.setValue(object.transcribe, forKey: "transcribe")
    }else{
        record.setValue("", forKey: "transcribe")
    }
    
    
    do {
        try record.managedObjectContext?.save() // **193 This is the Crash Line**
    } catch {
        let saveError = error as NSError
        Functions.log(saveError.localizedDescription)
        Crashlytics.crashlytics().setCustomValue(saveError.localizedDescription, forKey: "saveError")
    }
```

Comment: Your call stack implies that the update & save is not being done on the main thread. If that isn’t intentional then that’s probably the issue. Don’t cross threads with CoreData unless you’re  using a Private Queue and appropriate measures.